# How to combine generator of generators?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to combine a generator of generators so that when I call list() on said generator I get a list of the elements of the generators all toghether, not a list of generators. For example, I am currently doing:

```
list(itertools.chain((i for i in range(j)) for j in range(3)))
```

which is returning:

```
[<generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x7fc48921e200>,
<generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x7fc48921eeb8>,
<generator object <genexpr>.<genexpr> at 0x7fc48921e7d8>]
```

But i want it to return something like:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: You were close: [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

Comment: Why use generators at all? Why not just `[i for j in range(3) for i in range(j)]`? (although, it sounds like you want `[i for j in range(4) for i in range(j)]` going on your expected output....)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((i for i in range(j+1)) for j in range(3)))
# [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
```

`range(j)` is not won't give your desired output. You have to use `range(j+1)`

You could be done like this without using the iterator.

```
In [58]: list(i for j in range(3) for i in range(j+1))
Out[58]: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: `list(<gen-exp>)` -> `[<equiv list comp>]`